# URL rewriting with PHP variable

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

So I know the basics of URL rewriting, but there was something more complex that I couldn't get done or know if it can be done.

From:

```
http://www.example.com/file.php?name=Sam&id=23
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/Sam/file/23
```

I basically want to know if this is possible and if it is, how it can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$2.php?name=$1&id=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on [so]. Please explain a bit what is going on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below **htaccess** redirection rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$2.php?name=$1&id=$3 [L]
```

To get the vales use in php

```
$_GET['name'];//Sam
$_GET['id'];//23
```